How can dock image while selecting refernce
I'm trying to select the reference to the image for this I am trying to drag my mouse on to my image But when I am doing it the image is shifting according to how i am dragging my mouse for selecting the refernce. For this, I used AI to correct it and it still did not solve the problem if not added one.
def drawBackground(self, painter: QPainter, rect: QRectF):
    display_width = self._parent.width()
    display_height = self._parent.height()
    image_width = self._image.width()
    image_height = self._image.height()

# Maintain aspect ratio
    image_aspect_ratio = image_width / image_height
    display_aspect_ratio = display_width / display_height

    if display_aspect_ratio > image_aspect_ratio:
    # Scale based on height
      scaled_height = display_height
      scaled_width = image_aspect_ratio * scaled_height
    else:
    # Scale based on width
      scaled_width = display_width
      scaled_height = scaled_width / image_aspect_ratio

# Center the image in the display area
    image_pos_x = (display_width - scaled_width) / 2
    image_pos_y = (display_height - scaled_height) / 2

# Save the current state of the painter before transformation
    painter.save()

# Apply scaling and translation to the painter
    painter.translate(image_pos_x, image_pos_y)
    painter.scale(scaled_width / image_width, scaled_height / image_height)

# Draw the image (this ensures the image is scaled and translated properly)
    painter.drawImage(QRectF(0, 0, image_width, image_height), self._image)

# Restore painter to its previous state (removes the transformation)
    painter.restore()

# Now draw any overlays like crosshairs, ROI, etc., in the same coordinates as the image.
# Ensure any reference elements are drawn relative to the scaled and translated image.
# For example, you can draw a crosshair at the center of the image:
    crosshair_x = image_width / 2
    crosshair_y = image_height / 2
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 2))  # Set crosshair color and thickness
    painter.drawLine(crosshair_x - 10, crosshair_y, crosshair_x + 10, crosshair_y)  # Horizontal line
    painter.drawLine(crosshair_x, crosshair_y - 10, crosshair_x, crosshair_y + 10)  # Vertical 

